Will using a reference or a pointer give better performance?
I have 2 pieces of code.
The first one uses references:
void swap(int& a, int& b) {
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

int main() {
    int x{10};
    int y{20};
    swap(x, y);
}

and the second one uses pointers:
void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    int* temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

int main() {
    int x{10};
    int y{20};
    swap(&x, &y);
}

Can someone please explain to me which one will give the best performance and less memory cost?
(in this case, I want to use a temp variable not a = a+b; b = a - b; a = a-b or a = a ^ b; ... etc)

The second example doesn't do what you think it does.

Since the second one doesn't swap anything, it probably is not a viable contender.

You really should worry about correctness before performance, especially at such a low level.

Assuming you'll fix the 2nd version (by derefrencing the pointers), my guess is that the performance will be the same. But only measurement will give a definite answer.

i so sorry about the second one,  so let say i pass in swap (x,y). So which one will give best perfomence.

std::swap It beats both of your implementations.

If you are lucky, the std::swap could be implemented using a processor's swap instruction, which is more efficient than any code you can write.

The second example function you wrote:
void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    int* temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

Doesn't do anything. It doesn't swap the values pointed to by a and b. It only swaps the pointer values of the temporary parameters passed in.  Even pointers are passed by value.
This is probably what you meant:
void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

That implementation using pointers above and your original reference based version are equivalent. We can even compare the generated assembly on godbolt:
reference version: https://www.godbolt.org/z/b1zrYzv9Y
a$ = 8
b$ = 16
void swap(int &,int &) PROC                              ; swap, COMDAT
        mov     r8d, DWORD PTR [rcx]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdx]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rcx], eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], r8d
        ret     0
void swap(int &,int &) ENDP                              ; swap

pointer version: https://www.godbolt.org/z/4Pbzqc5e4
a$ = 8
b$ = 16
void swap(int *,int *) PROC                              ; swap, COMDAT
        mov     r8d, DWORD PTR [rcx]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdx]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rcx], eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], r8d
        ret     0
void swap(int *,int *) ENDP   

You can see they produce identical assembly code.
The TLDR on passing by reference vs pointer is that the compiler just treats "passing by reference" as syntactic sugar for passing by pointer.  That statement might trigger some language lawyers to correct me on other cases I'm forgetting about. But it holds for simple examples.
Also, in case you are curious, your original pointer implementation that had the bug I spoke of above generates almost no code when optimizations are turned on (beyond the function stub itself). The compiler can infer that the function doesn't do anything:
https://www.godbolt.org/z/ExKMPTW6o
a$ = 8
b$ = 16
void swap(int *,int *) PROC                              ; swap, COMDAT
        ret     0
void swap(int *,int *) ENDP  

